# Batch for loop delimeters

Tags: batch-file

Since Windows cmd syntax is ridiculously and unnecessarily complex and difficult to read, I'm having a hard time figuring out the right way to type this. Basically I'm just trying to create a for loop that runs:

> sc query | findstr SERVICE_NAME

Then takes the services from the output and runs:

> sc sdshow "SERVICE_NAME"

Here's what I've been trying:

> for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %a IN ("sc query | findstr SERVICE_NAME") DO sc sdshow %a

But apparently the delimeter is selecting the 2nd token in the command that I type, not the output. I thought it worked similar to: "cut -d " " -f2," but apparently not. Is there even a way to do this in the terrible monstrosity that is Windows cmd syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, you were *really* close. In batch, you manipulate the output of a command with a `for` loop using single quotes (`'`). Also, you need to escape the pipe inside of the command with a `^`.

Inside of batch files, you need to call the for loop variables with two `%` signs (although you only need one if you're typing it on the command line).

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('sc query ^| findstr "SERVICE_NAME"') do sc sdshow %%a
```